# How to record and pass responses between pages of Google Forms and to Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I would like to create a form with multiple question pages, where clicking the "Next" button of a page would automatically record the response onto Google Sheets (to collect data even if the user doesn't click "Submit" at the end).

Once the "Next" button is clicked on the current page, the response of the current page will be passed through some computation on Google Cloud or Google Sheets which would select the content to be displayed on the following page.

It seems like Google Forms can only retrieve the responses when the "Submit" button is clicked on, and the "Submit" button can only appear once at the end of the Form (and thus, cannot lead to another page of questions).

It also seems like the Google Apps Script API cannot create a trigger for the "Next" button in Google Forms.

I have tried using the "Submit" button to retrieve the responses of a page and to record them into Google Sheets.  However, the "Submit" button automatically redirects to an "End of Survey" page on Google Forms. There seems to be no option to redirect back to a page with questions to collect additional responses.

I have also tried creating a function in Apps Script which would retrieve the responses from the current page and select the content for the following page from a Google Sheets document, based on the current responses.  However, there seems to be no way of triggering this function because it appears that the API does not support triggering with the "Next" button at the end of each page.

Answer (score 0):

[According to this documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en) you can create different sections in the form (which can act as the "next" button you want), this can let you "change" the questions you ask your users based on what they've answered.

However, it is not possible to use a script to get the information as the user is responding, you can only access a form's responses after they have submitted them, as detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response).